# 'hostname' equivalent on windows

Tags: java, linux, windows, jsch

I want a feature in my program to switch user and execute shell commands on the same host using java. For which I'm using JSch, which basically does an ssh to the same host with given user credentials.

The problem is, for Linux based machines I can run 'hostname' command and get the hostname to connect, but with Windows platform there no such command that returns the hostname as the only output which I can use.

Is there any script or command that i can run to get the IP or hostname for Windows?

Comment: But that returns a whole bunch of information that i don't want, i can extract the ip from that information but i'm lookig for a straight forward command like 'hostname' in linux

Comment: what about 127.0.01

Comment: Also can you `ssh` to windows without a ssh server

Comment: Does not the `hostname` command works on Windows. It does work on my Windows 7 box

Comment: I can recall using `hostname` command on windows in XP age.

Answer (score 1):

First, `hostname` command exists in Windows for quite some time.  What is the Windows version you are working on.

Go back to your real problem:  I don't think Windows provide built-in ssh server .  Even you install an SSH server yourself, I doubt it really allow you logon using another user with his privilege.

If you are just looking for a way to run command under another user, you can use `runas` in windows.

e.g.

```
runas /user:yourmachine\anotheruser yourCommand
```